# Can't update Android Studio: java.exe is modified?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to update AS from 2.2 RC to the stable 2.2, however, after downloading and installing, I get this error:

[image]

The first error isn't a problem, it's just a file I accidentally dropped in, but the second one isn't letting me update. Is my java.exe corrupt? What can I do to fix it? Do I have to download AS again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ignored the error and AS updated successfully. No build errors, nothing. Everythings working fine.

Comment: I have the same problem you had.  When I click the only option, which is to click on "Cancel" to close the dialog box and end the installation I end up back in Android Studio but the new version was not updated.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @Ab_ How have you ignored this error and How could you update AS to new version? what is the way?

Comment: Having the same problem after I updated java.security file. How exactly do you ignore it when the only option is to cancel the installation?